# Canvas blur function - no third party plug-ins

Tags: javascript, blur

I have been searching on the internet for a simple way to blur a canvas image. I thought it would be easy to find information about how to program the gaussian blur function but every time I found something, it always included a lot of unneeded functions like animation and so on. All I want is to `take an image` -> `draw it in canvas` -> `blur image`-> `output image to data` -> `apply the data to a div element` -> `then delete the canvas element.`

I saw this one about motion blur: [Better canvas motion blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693448/better-canvas-motion-blur) Which didn't require that much code. How do I do something similar but in gaussian blur instead of motion blur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you posted, the HTML5 globalAlpha property of the target image is changed to change its opacity, and then the image is painted 10 times on a different vertical point to create the illusion of a motion blur.

For a normal Gaussian blur, you can use the regular CSS3 filter / feGaussianBlur attributes. Check here for an example:

http://css-plus.com/2012/03/gaussian-blur/

In particular, the section named "SVG blur filter applied to a SVG image element"

There are more techniques to do this, including Javascript plugins like the following:

- http://blurjs.com/
- http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

However, the CSS3 filter / feGaussianBlur attributes should be the simplest to use, for your needs.

Comment: I did ask for something not third party plug-in, but I like the CSS part.. The main thing I hate about all this is that everything has to be optimized for every single browser..  But thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
blur = function (canvasId) {

    var c = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;

    var offset = 3;

    for (var i=1; i<=8; i+=1) {
        ctx.drawImage(c, offset, 0, c.width - offset, c.height, 0, 0, c.width-offset, c.height);
        ctx.drawImage(c, 0, offset, c.width, c.height - offset, 0, 0,c.width, c.height-offset);
    }
};
```

blur("myCanvas");

Comment: how is this implemented? ctx is not declared so I am guessing that you have some other 2D canvas elements set up before you call this function. Do you call blur(myCanvas); ?? thanks in advance.

Comment: No you call blur("mycanvasID");

Comment: `ctx` still isn't declared anywhere, so this won't work

Comment: Indeed, it says `var ctx = c.getContext("2d");`. Isn't it declared? It's the 2d-context of the element.